# Does Lenz's law tell us direction of induced emf or current?

Tags: electromagnetism, electrostatics, voltage, electromagnetic-induction

On [this wiki page,](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Faraday%27s_law_of_induction?oldformat=true#Mathematical_statement) it is written that

> It is possible to find out the direction of the [induced]
> ***electromotive force (emf)*** directly from Faraday’s law, without invoking Lenz's law. A left hand rule helps doing that [...]

and [on the page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lenz%27s_law?oldformat=true) on Lenz's law it is written  that

> It is a qualitative law that specifies the direction of ***induced
> current,*** but states nothing about its magnitude

In the first, it is implied that Lenz's law tells us the direction of induced emf, but in the second it is implied that the law tells us the direction of induced current. Which version of the Lenz law is correct? Are both correct and equivalent? Why?

---

Note: This question was originally part of [this question,](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/693002/what-is-definition-of-direction-of-induced-emf) but I found that it made my question too lengthy and confusing.

Comment: Link to my answer to your previous question, which you edited and separated to this question (first point has the answer): https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/693018/253727

Comment: This question has been asked before and answered and the note written by the OP is not really a valid excuse for reposting it.

Answer (score 0):

Lenz's law, as usually understood, tells us the direction of the induced emf. It does so by referring to what effects (forces or flux generation) that the emf *would have* *in a closed circuit*. These closed circuit effects are due to the current that would flow as a result of the emf.

So the logic is a little involved. Nonetheless the law does tell us about the direction of the induced emf even if the circuit is open (as, for example when a moving rod, not connected to anything, cuts magnetic flux).

Comment: I think the direction of induced EMF refers the direction of orientation of the imaginary battery which is formed during the change of flux.

Comment: Lenz's law does indeed tell you which way round the imaginary battery would go – if you like to think in terms of batteries. I find it easier simply to imagine the direction in which positive charges would be pushed by the Lorentz force. But it's a matter of taste.